# Is it possible that I am using input and output ports directly on Raphael.js rectangle object?

Tags: graphiti-js

I want to know that can u used Graphiti.js Input/Output ports on Raphael.js Rectangle Objects?
so that it is easy for me to get functionality for set operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use Graphiti because it is built up on Raphael.